# Redirecting the Source Code errors in CMake

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake

I am building the C Project using CMAKE. My build is working fine, but the problem is if any errors and warnings are there in the source code it's displaying on the command prompt. How can I redirect warnings and compilation errors to a file, So it's easy for me to resolve one by one? I am running my CMake using the following commands in the batch file.

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
make 
pause
```

Comment: Did something like `cmake -G [...] 2> error.cmake.txt` do the job?

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. It's redirecting the messages present in CMakeLists.txt, but after generating the makefile it will go compilation of the code using make command I need to redirect that Compile time errors/warnings.

Comment: Then redirect the `make` command instead: e.g  `make 2>errors.log`

Comment: Thank you @MikeKinghan.Previously I tried to make >errors.log.Now it's working